# Gradle have an error but it build fine

Tags: android, api, gradle, runtime-error, android-appcompat

There is an error appearing in the gradle file but it built and never showed in console, the application works fine but I think it is going to crash on other devices.

[image]

how can I fix it? And how can I copy the error from the tooltip?
Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mol.saherproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
        compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.10'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.halysongoncalves:pugnotification:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

any help please......

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see this error is that the dependency graph of your app contains different versions of support libraries. Although your build.gradle file only declares `25.1.1`, one of the other dependencies relies on support libraries version `24.0.0`. Run the following in the command line to see where that dependency come from:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies
```

Analyze the output and note any occurrences of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0` (or any other support library with version `24.0.0`). The dependency graph makes it easy to trace this dependency to the root dependency, which your project explicitly declares.

To solve this issue, exclude the transitive dependency from the module that uses it. For example, if `com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4` relied on `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0`, you'd change the declaration to:

```
compile('com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4') {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Then you have to make sure that the right version of `appcompat-v7` is present in your project.

Additionally, you might want to file an issue to the GitHub project of the library that declares an old support library dependency, or submit a pull request updating the version.